# Webview Causing Fatal Exception WebViewCoreThread

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting this Fatal exception while loading an HTML file from sdcard in a `WebView`. This happens only to few HTML files; others are loading properly . What can be the problem?

Can't resolve this issue.

```
E/SensorManager(2425): Error: Sensor Event is null for Sensor: {Sensor name="MPL Accelerometer",vendor="Invensense", version=1, type=1, "Accelerometer", vendor="Invensense", version=1, type=1, maxRange=19.6133, resolution=0.039226603, power=5.5, minDelay=1000}
08-06 23:52:41.170: D/chromium(2425): Unknown chromium error: -6
08-06 23:52:41.250: E/Web Console(2425): Uncaught ReferenceError: OTW is not defined at file:///storage/emulated/0/123/ads/1/index.html:2104

FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.DeviceMotionService$2.run(DeviceMotionService.java:103)
    at android.webkit.DeviceMotionService$2.run(DeviceMotionService.java:103)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:814)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: then give us some code. the error log isnt realy enough...

Comment: seems like there should be more to that error, can you post the rest, and the html file causing the issue as well?

Comment: I have edited my question again with few more lines which i get along with exception for your reference , and the html file is confidential which cannot be shared

Comment: I predict this issue is because of handling device motion in html file . Is this not supported in Android ? . Is it possible to load html in webview which has DeviceMotionEvent. Please help

Comment: Still this issue persists . is there any other way to fix this issue in android ?